# window.print() prints blank page

Tags: javascript

I get blank page while printing. The border(it may be the frame) is printed. But not the content inside the frame. if we manually print the new page it is getting printed correctly. Why this happen?

```
var printwindow = window.open('', '', 'fullScreen=no');
printwindow.document.write('<iframe id="docPrint" onLoad="window.print()" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://localhost:8080/hiring/docs/Keneth _1340800082258/Keneth _resume_1340800082258.pdf"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are injecting it dynamically, try escaping `/` in `</iframe>`:

```
'.....<\/iframe>'
```

Also apply `onload` to window not iframe:

```
printwindow.onload = printwindow.print;
```

So try this instead:

```
var printwindow = window.open('', '', 'fullScreen=no');
printwindow.document.write('<iframe id="docPrint" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://localhost:8080/hiring/docs/Keneth _1340800082258/Keneth _resume_1340800082258.pdf"></iframe>');
printwindow.onload = printwindow.print;
```

I am not sure if browser will take your pdf file and print it, if pdf open directly in browser then there is a print option in browser pdf plugin separately.

Comment: It will not trigger print dialogue. Just loads the page only. That's why I put it in iframe onload

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible with JavaScript.

I don't know which language your server is written in, but it may be possible to make your PDF [auto print](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=157&t=Create_an_Auto-Print_PDF).

Comment: How will do it with javascript? I am new to js

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible with JS

Comment: I wish it was possible. and I knew it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the window.print() from the iframe is referring to the window that contains the iFrame, not the content inside of it.

Comment: But this is also not working. I think the following code is for printing the content inside the frame. `printwindow.document.getElementById('docPrint').focus(); printwindow.document.getElementById('docPrint').contentWindow.print();`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for other problem and found it open, so try to do it.

**Watch to load of your iframe and get the content inside of it, cuz you have to handle the loading from this iframe or you can ajax GET the entire page and save it at iframeContent**

```
let iframeContent = document.getElementById("docPrint").innerHTML;
const iframePage = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
iframePage.document.write(iframeContent);
iframePage.document.close();
iframePage.focus();
iframePage.onload = relatorio.print;
```